# Sheaf of meromorphic functions on an integral scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-theory

It is a theorem that the sheaf of meromorphic functions on an integral scheme is equal to the constant sheaf where each open set is assigned the function field of the scheme. [See, for example, the Stacks Project.](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X5) I would like to know why this is true.

Recall that the sheaf of meromorphic functions is the sheafification of the presheaf that assigns to each open set $U$ the set $\mathcal R_X(U)^{-1}\mathcal O_X(U)$, where $\mathcal R(U)$ is the set of regular sections. In the case of an integral scheme, $\mathcal R(U)$ is simply all nonzero sections.

Comment: (Let us assume the scheme is connected to avoid technicalities.)

Comment: I meant it is not true that $R_X(U)^{-1}O_X(U)\to O_{X,\xi}$ is an isomorphism in general. The sheaf of meromorphic functions on an integral scheme is a constant sheaf.

Comment: @QiL'8 Why is your second statement true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the presheaf $U\mapsto K(\mathcal{O}_X(U))$, where $K(A)$ is the quotient field of an integral domain $A$. Then $\mathcal{K}$, the sheaf of total quotient rings of $\mathcal{O}$ (i.e. sheaf of meromorphic functions on $X$), is by definition the sheafification of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $K$ be the constant sheaf $\mathcal{O}_\xi$ on $X$, $\xi$ is the generic point of $X$.

Actually, there is a natural morphism of presheaves $\rho:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow K$ defined below:

For any $f=g/h\in K(\mathcal{O}_X(U))$, $f_\xi=g_\xi/h_\xi\in K(\mathcal{O}_\xi)=\mathcal{O}_\xi$. Define $\rho_U(f)=f_\xi$, then $\rho$ is the restriction of rational functions to their germs at $\xi$, so $\rho$ is automatically a morphism of presheaves. By the universal property of sheafification, there is a morphism of sheaves $\bar\rho: \mathcal{K}\rightarrow K$ induced by $\rho$.

**Claim**: $\bar\rho$ is an *isomorphism* of sheaves.

**Proof**: For any affine open subset $U=\operatorname{Spec}A\subset X$, $\mathcal{F}(U)=K(\mathcal{
O}_X(U))=K(A)\cong \mathcal{O}_\xi$, so $\rho_U:\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow K(U)=\mathcal{O}_\xi$ is an isomorphism. Since affine open subsets form a topological basis of the Zariski topology of $X$, $\rho_x: \mathcal{F}_x\rightarrow K_x$ is an isomorphism for any $x\in X$.

Since $\mathcal{K}_x$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}_x$ via the natural morphism of presheaves $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$, $\bar\rho_x:\mathcal{K}_x\rightarrow K_x$ is an isomorphism for any $x\in X$, hence $\bar\rho$ is an isomorphism of sheaves. QED

Comment: Thank you! This makes it very clear.